# Optimizing member variable access

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

May C++ compilers optimize the following loop to an infinite loop

```
this->m_stop=0;
while(!this->m_stop)
    {
//  do stuff
    }
```

This question is relevant even in a single-threaded context, since a call inside the loop may affect the status flag indirectly.

Comment: Yes a compiler might do that. You can avoid it by making the variable `volatile` though.

Comment: not if "do stuff" modifies `this->m_stop` potentially

Comment: Generally speaking, an optimization is legal if, and only if, a standards-compliant program cannot tell the difference in guaranteed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no possible way that the body of the loop can legitimately change `m_stop`, then this is a permissible optimization.

If the compiler cannot see the contents of the functions in the loop, then it must assume they can change `m_stop`.

If a pointer or reference to `m_stop` or `*this` is stored somewhere accessible to the code that runs in the body of the loop, then the compiler would have to do more extensive analysis to determine whether it is safe to assume `m_stop` doesn't change. If it cannot do this analysis, then it must assume `m_stop` may change if the body of the loop changes anything that could potentially refer to `m_stop`.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler can only carry out optimisations which do not affect the observable behaviour of a well-formed program. This is commonly known as the *as-if* rule; the program *must* behave as-if it was executed by some abstract machine following the standard to the letter, but an implementation may change things about the execution to make it run faster so long as the program acts in the same way.

As such, the compiler cannot optimise your code into an infinite loop unless it can prove that it doesn't affect the observable behaviour of the program. Of course, if you have undefined behaviour somewhere, then all bets are off.

Answer (score -1):

If `this->m_stop` is non-volatile and the compiler can know that the value of `this->m_stop` does not alter it's value (ie that the condition will always be true).

Perhaps it could (in some cases) know that the condition will remain true even if `this->m_stop` is volatile. But still this scenario means it must still basically evaluate at least `this->m_stop` for each iteration through the loop (even if it knows the result will be `0`). Normally a compiler won't know that.

Also the case where `this->m_stop` alters it value is a possibility if the compiler somehow can know that the value would be `0` at every start of the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't using [std::memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) be a better option than `volatile`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl That would depend on the purpose I think. `volatile` isn't about intre thread synchronization, but rather intra thread operation ordering.

Comment: @skyking volatile is about variables that may be modified by things external to the program  ... using it for other threads is insufficient and unnecessary

Comment: @M.M That would be the layman explanation of the keyword. However as defined the volatile accesses are part of the observable behavior of the program. For example they need not actually be things modified by things external to the program.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment

Comment: @skyking In no way can volatile make a difference here. You've either got the case in which there is an _unordered_ write and read to the variable from different threads in which case you've got undefined behaviour whether your variable is volatile or not, OR the read/write IS ordered in which case a plain integer works just as well. Volatile is never useful for multithreading anymore. Just use a `std::atomic` if you want unordered cross thread access with well defined behaviour.

Comment: @MikeVine Why do you think there's an undefined behavior? Consider my comment that the `volatile` is **not** about thread syncronization - why then keep complaining about that `volatile` is not useful for multithreading (synchronization)?

Comment: @skyking In which case this answer is even more stupid than I thought. So now you've got the possibility that either the compiler can't tell if its changed and so reads the value anyway (so volatile makes no difference) or the compiler can prove the value doesn't changed (so volatile makes this force an unnecessary read which is guaranteed to be pointless) like your paragraph 2 says. A well formed program can NOT tell the difference with volatile here so adding 'volatile' to force the read is wrong in every-way. Simply don't mention volatile outside of anything except interacting with hardware

Comment: @MikeVine I think your comment shows sign of misreading my answer. Granted the first sentence is incomplete - that's my bad. Otherwise it means that both has to be fulfilled to be able to optimize it away and effectively make it an formally infinite loop. Note that even if the compler knows the value beforehand the reading of a `volatile` variable is still mandatory (that's basically the definition of `volatile`). By the way where did you find the mention that the program don't interact with HW?

Comment: @MikeVine Also you didn't answer why you think there's an undefined behavior. How do you think downvoting will help (improvement) if you don't bother clarifying what you're meaning is wrong or bad?

Comment: I mentioned that undefined behaviour in the context of multi threading unordered read/write. Adding volatile doesn't change whether its undefined behavoir or not. The standard simply defines it to be undefined behavoir in that scenario. (Of course, if this answer isn't about multithreading, then this point is obviously pointless)